# ASP.NET Issues with Safari

Tags: asp.net, security, safari

I'm tracking customer issues with our contractor website. I've had quite a few customers complain that they are unable to access their account (on a secure server). Users will get a server error. When I ask them to try on a different browser the issue goes away.

I don't know where to begin to look for the reason Safari has issues with our servers. The site is built using ASP.NET. I know next to nothing about Safari issues and how Safari handles data transmission. I don't know if Safari doesn't like the way we save cookies, if it's a validation issue, or what.

The "login" button seems to be sending the request to the server, because our contractor is getting the error logs. (They are not sending us these error logs, unfortunately, so I can't really review them myself. Contractors don't like it when you ask to see their logs.)

Does anyone have the vaguest form of advice? Have you had any similar errors or kinky issues with Safari?

Comment: You really need to get the client-side error message or get your hands on server-side logs.

Comment: Yeah, without more information (which may be in those logs) there really isn't much you can do about it unless you can reproduce the issue yourself.  Even then, the logs will be immensely helpful.

Comment: Or at the very least post your url so those with Safari can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I know I wasn't giving much information. I'd give the URL, but it's for federal student loans, so I'm limited by security. Working with the government is so wonderful. Why get something fixed in a day when you can take two months.

Comment: Try dropping in ELMAH to capture the server error: http://nuget.org/packages/elmah